# HDD partition disappearing and being replaced by "Windows Reserved" partition. Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: partitioning, windows

My machine has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD with both Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on the SSD. My HDD has a single partition occupying the entire disk that I have been using exclusively with Ubuntu.

Recently, I went to access the HDD partition and it wasn't found. I opened the Disk Manger and saw that the partition was gone. Instead, there was a very small (few hundred MB) partition labeled "Microsoft Reserved" and the rest was shown as free space.

I used `fsck -b 32768` to repair the disk, my partition came back, and I thought that was that.

But today I went to access my partition and the exact same thing happened. I fixed it again with `fsck -b` and that's where I am now.

What would be the permanent fix for this? Do I just need to back up my data elsewhere and reformat the drive?

**EDIT**

Restarted my computer and it happened again. My partition was missing and a small Microsoft one was showing instead. Running `sudo parted -l` shows:

```
Model: ATA ADATA SU800 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   87.6GB  87.0GB  ext4
 3      87.6GB  128GB   40.5GB  ntfs                               msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
```

I repaired the disk again with `fsck -b 32768`, it was working as expected. `sudo parted -l` results:

```
Model: ATA ADATA SU800 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   87.6GB  87.0GB  ext4
 3      87.6GB  128GB   40.5GB  ntfs                               msftdata


Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel? OK                                                             
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  16.8MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
```

Comment: When Windows partitions a drive, it adds a Microsoft Reserved partition. That has to be before any NTFS partitions. Are you running some command to redo the drive? Order on drive is important: msftres
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition

Comment: Need to see your existing partitions. Run  `sudo parted -l` and post up the output into your question.

Comment: Normally Windows installs the MRP on the same disk as it's system. Don't see how it ended up on your HDD. That aside the GPT on that disk is corrupted. I assume sda3 is W10, so where's your data stored?

Comment: After repairing the disk, my data is restored to the HDD. I can access that drive like normal and the Disks app shows a single, 1 TB partition as expected. However, what Disks shows does not match what ```sudo parted``` shows above.